# member can change their password

Tags: php

I have made an script which should enable users to change their password. but i get error
confirmation password and new password doesnt match..
here is the code

```
<?
session_start();   
include 'db.php';

 if($_POST['username']!="") {
  $username = $_POST['username'];  
}
else die("No Username was passed");
if($_POST['password']!="") {
  $password = $_POST['password'];
}
else die("No Password was passed");
if($_POST['newpassword']!="") {
  $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
}
else die("No NewPassword was passed");
if($_POST['confirmnewpassword']!="") {
  $newpassword = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];
}
else die("No Confirm Password was passed");

$username = $_POST['username'];  
$password = $_POST['password'];
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    if(!$result){
        echo "The username entered does not exist!";
    }
    else
        if($password != mysql_result($result, 0)){
            echo "Entered an incorrect password";
            }

    if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword){
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$newpassword' WHERE username = '$username'");      
    }

    if(!$sql){
        echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
    }
    else{
        echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
    }

  ?>
```

here is the form Code

```
<form action="lostpw.php" method="post" name="" id="">
                                            <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr> 
                                                  <td width="22%">Username</td>
                                                  <td width="78%"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo "". $_SESSION['username'] ."" ?>"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                  <td width="22%">Old password</td>
                                                  <td width="78%"><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                  <td>New Password</td>
                                                  <td><input name="newpassword" type="newpassword" value=""></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                </tr>
                                                  <td>Confirm </td>
                                                  <td><input name="confirmnewpassword" type="confirmnewpassword" value=""></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr> 
                                                  <td><a href="home.php">Back</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
</form>
```

where am i doing wrong.

Comment: You have no protection from [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to save password in PLAIN TEXT ? 2. Did you aware of SQL Injection ?

Comment: Why are you storing plaintext passwords?

Comment: Your logic for displaying error/success messages is also wrong, look at the last 'else', it makes no sense at all.

Comment: I can't quite tell where it's going wrong, yet I do know that all (PHP) files must contain `session_start();` if it's not in your other PHP files.

Comment: and do not use `mysql_query()`! Try MySQLi !

Comment: else die is a good place to look. There are better ways of handling user input.

Comment: You are setting newpassword twice. The second is where you would presumably be setting confirmnewpassword.

Comment: Previous comment is not the problem as you set the variables again below. Still worth fixing

Answer (score 1):

You are not stopping in any case of bad behavior. You are not stopping the execution of the script after:

```
if(!$result){
        echo "The username entered does not exist!";
    } else if($password != mysql_result($result, 0)){
        echo "Entered an incorrect password";
}
```

Therefore:

```
if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword){
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$newpassword' WHERE username = '$username'");      
}
```

will be always evaluated.

Also

```
if(!$sql){
    echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
} else {
    echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
}
```

means: when the query fails (`$sql = false`, `!$sql = true`) print a success message, otherwise print a failure message. I don't think that's what you want. You may want to invert those two blocks.

Comment: i got it working thanhs

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have that exclamation point, which is an inverter.  That's saying 'If the query DIDN'T WORK, say congratulations, else if it DID work, give an error message.'  The following:

```
if(!$sql){
    echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
}
else{
    echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
}
```

SHOULD BE:

```
if($sql){
    echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
}
else{
    echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
}
```

Comment: The other post about the $result line is also accurate, although it didn't answer your question.

Comment: i havnt store the password in plain text. they encrypted in md5 stored in database,,,,

Comment: @Aamir: You commented on the wrong post. ;)